# Помогите решить проблему с кликером на js!

Tags: javascript

(Это моя первая вещь созданная на жаваскрипт) я сделал по приколу кликер, и там произошла ошибка,
что когда ты пытаешься "Прокачаться" - то ничего не происходит

```html
<html>


<head>

  <title>крутая игра пра куке </title>

  <style>
    button {
      border-radius: 60px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body background="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/559782693982961684/964193433101140019/SPOILER_m.png?width=910&height=910">


  <script language="javascript">
    alert('JavaScript подключён');

    var kuki = 0,
      uvel = 1;

    function KHO() {
      kuki = kuki + uvel;
      document.getElementById('kuke').innerHTML = kuki;
    }

    function PRO() {
      var cost;
      cost = 250 * Math.pow(uvel, 2);

      if (kuki >= cost) {
        kuki = kuki - cost;
        uvel = uvel * 2;
        cost = 250 * Math.pow(uvel, 2);

        document.getElementById('CEM').innerHTML = kuki;
        document.getElementById('PLU').innerHTML = uvel;
        document.getElementById('COS').innerHTML = cost;

      }
    }
  </script>

  <table border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4">
        <font size=100>
          <h7 id="kuke">0</h7>
        </font>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th width="25%" align="right">Куке за раз -
        <h7 id="PLU">1</h7>
      </th>
      <th width="25%" align="center"><button onclick="KHO()"><img src="https://pixy.org/src/8/89270.png" alt="Кажется, что куке , каторый тут была, удолили(" width="100" height="100"></button></th>
      <th width="25%" align="center"><button onclick="PRO()">пракачаца</button></th>
      <th width="25%" align="left">Цена -
        <h7 id="COS">250</h7>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <script src="yopta.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: осваивайте отладку кода и пр. Ссылка вверху

Comment: По коду видно, что ничего не произойдёт, пока не нажмёте круглую кнопку 250 раз. После изменения переменной **uvel** до следующего случая, когда кнопка **прокачаться** будет вызывать какое-то событие, круглую кнопку придётся нажать 1000 раз, потом 4000 раз. В такой ситуации даже ошибка не выскочит, пока не будет сделано нужное количество нажатий.